# Create a unique key when mapping over array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a form that contains an object of arrays. I'm getting the error `Encountered two children with the same key,`1:$[object Object]`.`. How do I create a unique key?

```
renderPositions() {
  const profileCandidateCollection = this.props.profileCandidate;
  const careerHistoryPositions = profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.careerHistoryPositions;

  if (careerHistoryPositions) {
    return careerHistoryPositions.map((key, position) => {
      return (
        <CareerHistoryPositionsUpdateForm
          key={key}
          company={position.company}
          title={position.title}
        />
      )
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost correct. If you want to use the index in `map` the element comes first and the index goes second:

```
return careerHistoryPositions.map((position, key) => {
   return (
     <CareerHistoryPositionsUpdateForm
       key={key}
       company={position.company}
       title={position.title}
     />
   )
})
```

The index works for keys but [in React it's discouraged](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). Instead, use a unique identifier:

> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies
>   a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your
>   data as keys:

So for each item that gets added to `careerHistoryPositions` add another key with a unique ID and use that as the list key. In the past, I've used the `v4` method from the [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package to create unique ID's.

Comment: Thanks, I did read that in the React docs. Your suggestion to create a unique Id for each object is a good idea.